# Get hash with preg_match from source code

Tags: php, preg-match

i want to get a hash from link source code and stock it in a variable
the source code is :

```html
Profile.init({"user_id":37462,"loc":null,"back":"Leeter Leeter","last_names":[],"max_name_len":280,"hash_hash":"8cc8f7b2dcb4331676"});
```

The hash I want is: 8cc8f7b2dcb4331676

I tried with this code but it didn't work.

```html
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("Link");
if (preg_match("/hash_hash":"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"/i", $data, $matches))
     print "The hash is: $matches[1]";
else
     print "The page doesn't have a hash";
```

Comment: "Link" is $data = file_get_contents("Link") is just a string. Where does Profile.init comes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern with preg_match_all() :

```
'/"hash_hash":"([^"]+)"/i'
```

Example :

```
$x='Profile.init({"user_id":37462,"loc":null,"back":"Leeter Leeter","last_names":[],"max_name_len":280,"hash_hash":"8cc8f7b2dcb4331676"})';
preg_match_all('/"hash_hash":"([^"]+)"/i',$x,$matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Demo : https://eval.in/535936